# Are these functionalities possible in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am a bit confused and i asked this question just for confirmation.
Please do reply.

Is there any API available to access or intercept calls, sms, emails, mms, phone power up/down, websites viewed.
I need to maintain log files for all incoming call, outgoing calls, incoming sms, outgoing sms, sent and received emails, sent and received mms,
also when phone gets power up or either switched on and switched off (for this i also need to know if i can start my application as the phone switched on.)
Also i need to block some incoming /outgoing call, text messages, mms, websites. But if i cannot access them, i think i can't block them too.

i have searched and i found that intercepting calls and sms is not possible.
but i need to be sure.

So please reply.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is still that there is no possibility to intercept an incoming call inside your own application. For the current release of WP7 this is not going to change.

Comment: @Deeps: All sending and receiving are handled by the OS. You cannot intercept it (as of now in the current releases). If that answers your query, mark it as answered.